# How would world looks like if indians doesn't exist at all?

Tags: society

Indians invented zero, fibre optics & lot of things etc.

some Indian scientist Jagadish Chandra Bose said plants have feelings etc which leads to wireless technology etc., so How would world looks like if Indians doesn't exist at all?

Comment: As interesting as that might be, it is very hard to answer. Do you mean to imply that the whole culture would be missing? India has been in the centre of a lot Human development for centuries. As a consequence, it is probably too broad to answer.

Comment: "Indians" is not a very well defined concept. As pointed by MakorDal, India has been colonized by people at some point, when do we start considering them to be Indians ? If it is as soon as they are on the continent, then the scenario will also wipe out all population which original migration path went through India. Moreover I highly doubt that considering the whole Indian as only one culture make much sense. And finally to avoid the existence of Indian culture, what do you put instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indians did not start in India. Like any other human ethnicity, they started from Africa and choose to stop on the sub-continent.

If Indian culture hadn't existed as it is today,... well someone else would have had those idea. Differently, but sooner or later it would have happened.
Any idea that a human can have, another can too. That's accounted for in the way copyright works for example.

Indian culture might not have existed, but another one would have arisen. Either unique or linked to Asia or to the Middle East. For everything else, the history of war, conquest, colonization and so on would have pretty much taken the same shape. Maybe not in the details of who did what but in the sense that the first tool a human made was probably a rock to hit his neighbour on the head with.

Now if the sub-continent didn't exists, that's an interesting question : the difference in geographical shape would create a great difference in meteorology, sea current and so on.